# Game design: what is the approach of the functional, immutable language for developing classic games?

Tags: functional-programming, immutability

Imagine the classic 2d RPG game that has many instances of players that can change their positions, HP, inventory, skill-values, death lists and so on every time.

[image: Tibia Client]

How would an immutable language approach the design of such game? That is, would the immutability factor limit the development as the game is something that is always changing, or could it be used to design that game as effectively as in a traditional language?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293059/immutable-game-object-basic-functional-programming-question

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Functional Reactive Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028250/what-is-functional-reactive-programming). Its key concepts are signals and events, which represent values that change in time.

There is a list of various Haskell frameworks and resources [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_Reactive_Programming) at Haskell Wiki.

I'm not sure if it will directly help you to create a game, but I believe learning FRP concepts and ideas will give you new valuable insights.